# Error in R - Number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

Tags: r, linear-programming

I received this error when I tried running this code in R

```
const1 = c(1,1,1,1,1)
const2 = c(1,1,1,1,1)
const3 = c(1,1,1,1,1)
const4 = c(1,1,1,1,1)
const5 = c(1,1,1,1,1)
const6 = c(1,1,1,1,1)
const7 = c(35,16,125,25,40,5)
const8 = c(37,17,130,27,43,7)
const9 = c(39,18,136,29,46,8)
const10 = c(42,19,139,30,50,10)
const11 = c(45,20,144,33,52,11)
f.con <- rbind(const1,const2,const3,const4,const5,const6,const7,const8,const9,const10,const11)
```

Warning message:In rbind(const1, const2, const3, const4, const5, const6, const7,
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

Comment: some vectors have 5 and 6 elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get all the vectors in to a `list`, convert to `data.frame` with `map` and bind them into a single dataset

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(mget(ls(pattern = '^const\\d+$')), ~ as.data.frame(t(.x)))
```

Or with `unnest_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
mget(paste0('const', 1:11)) %>%
      tibble(col1 = .) %>% 
      unnest_wider(c(col1))
```

---

Or using `base R`, after creating a `list` of `vector`s, pad `NA` at the end for shorter list elements and then `rbind`

```
lst1 <- mget(paste0('const', 1:11))
do.call(rbind, unname(lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1)))))
#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1   NA
# [2,]    1    1    1    1    1   NA
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    1   NA
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    1   NA
# [5,]    1    1    1    1    1   NA
# [6,]    1    1    1    1    1   NA
# [7,]   35   16  125   25   40    5
# [8,]   37   17  130   27   43    7
# [9,]   39   18  136   29   46    8
#[10,]   42   19  139   30   50   10
#[11,]   45   20  144   33   52   11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the vectors in a list and use `sapply` to extract data from each.

```
data <- mget(paste0('const', 1:11))
t(sapply(data, `[`, 1:max(lengths(data))))

#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#const1     1    1    1    1    1   NA
#const2     1    1    1    1    1   NA
#const3     1    1    1    1    1   NA
#const4     1    1    1    1    1   NA
#const5     1    1    1    1    1   NA
#const6     1    1    1    1    1   NA
#const7    35   16  125   25   40    5
#const8    37   17  130   27   43    7
#const9    39   18  136   29   46    8
#const10   42   19  139   30   50   10
#const11   45   20  144   33   52   11
```